# RSelenium::rsDriver() do not start the seleinum server

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

hello everyone i try to work with RSelenium ,and i write the following code to start RSelenium server and it does not work even i change the browser and try all the versions

```
RSelenium::rsDriver(browser ="chrome")`
```

and the ouput gives me

```
Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  : 
  Selenium server  couldn't be started
```